# Using external babel configuration

Tags: node.js, next.js, babel-node

I'm using @babel/node package in my project

and when I run my project as:

> npm run dev

I'm getting this message in cmd window:

```
> Using external babel configuration 
> Location: "...(project folder path)\.babelrc"
```

And when I build my project jsx files, I received errors . 
How to solve it?

Dev dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/node": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
}
```

.babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel", "@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue, removed  "@babel/preset-env" in .babelrc file. Deleting this part solves the issue (worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

My `babel.rc` for developing js apps using nodejs is like this:

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env"],
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
    ],
    "env": {
        "development": {
          "sourceMaps": true,
          "retainLines": true
        }
    }
}
```

And my `dev` script is like this:

```
"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node src/index.js | pino-pretty",
```

I use `cross-env` and `pino`, you can remove it.

I hope helpful.